# Complete a calculation ("2+3=...") inside a buffer

Tags: org-mode, calc

I have a calculation in my org-mode buffer:

```python
7700*1/100 + 18000*2/100
```

I'm looking for the quicker way of completing it, and displaying it like this:

```python
7700*1/100 + 18000*2/100 = 437
```

My current way of doing this is a little harassing.

1. do the computation with calc embedded mode: `C-x * e`
2. leave the calc embedded mode: `q`
3. Copy the result
4. Revert the change(`C-x u`), append "=" and paste the result.

What is a quicker way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

```
(use-package macro-math
  :bind ("\C-x=" . macro-math-eval-region)
        ("\C-x~" . macro-math-eval-and-round-region))
```

And I have this note in my `emacs.org`:

```
NOTE: Edit macro-math.el and fix:
# ;;(delete-region beg end)
# (goto-char (region-end))
# (insert " = " rounded)
```

And there is an issue to support appending `= <result>` rather than replacing the equation with a result: https://github.com/nschum/macro-math.el/issues/2

Answer (score 1):

I hastily edited a little function that does this job. The expression to be evaluated must be a region containing an expression valid for the syntax of calc.
For example 1 + 2 will be evaluated and replaced by 3 and 1 + 2 => will be evaluated and replaced by 1 + 2 = 3.
Note that Calc's precedence rules impose parentheses in some cases, to return 437 the expression 7700 * 1/100 + 18000 * 2/100 = 437
must be written 7700 * (1/100) + 18000 * (2/100).
There are undoubtedly still things to be tweaked.

```
(defun evaluate-in-line (beg end)
  "Evaluates the math expression from the region with calc syntax. 
   The expression can be ended with => or not."
    (interactive (list (region-beginning) (region-end)) )
    (let ((evaluation(calc-eval(substring(buffer-string) (1- beg)(1- end)))))
      (when (stringp evaluation)
        (kill-region beg end)
        (save-excursion
          (insert(with-temp-buffer
                   (insert  evaluation)
                   (goto-char(point-min))
                  (when (search-forward  "\\evalto" nil t) (replace-match "")
                   (search-forward "\\to" nil t)
                   (replace-match "="))
                   (buffer-string)))))))
```

Evaluate this function with C-x C-e just after the last parentheses, select a region that content an algebraic expression. M-x evaluate-in-line to proceed. If you find it handy, you can save it in your init file and bind this function to some keysstrokes.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, yet I do not find this function useful as it is. Strangely enough, it seems to delete the multiplication operator (`*`) on the left part. Also, if I want to keep the details of the computation (which I do), it displays it with `=>` instead of `=`, which makes no sense: in mathematics, the latter has the meaning of an implication, not of an equality.

Comment: Also, while it is true that Calc has one particular precedence rule (as per the documentation states: "Calc gives ‘/’ lower precedence than ‘*’, so that ‘a/b*c’ is interpreted as ‘a/(b*c)’; this is not standard across all computer languages."), I think it does not give multiplication and division lower precedence than addition. So the parentheses do seem unnecessary in this example.